# Convert Hair Dryer to Variable Speed

Tags: speed, variable

I am using a hair dryer to increase oxygen/air levels in a torch assembly for a forge for metal work. I need to be able to increase/decrease the fan motor speed smoothly and more precisely than the low/high setting. I have a fundamental understanding of electronics and some background in the basics of different electronic components such as resistors, capacitors, diodes etc. It would appear high/low setting simply bypasses or does not bypass a diode limiting negative energy cycles thus roughly halving the speed of the fan motor when the diode is in the circuit blocking negative AC pulses. Is there a way to insert a component into the circuit which would limit the power going to the fan motor and thus reduce the motor speed?

Comment: Such a motor is probably not designed for such usage.  To have an answerable question, you'd first need to determine the actual type of motor, eg, a brushed AC *universal* motor found in a lightweight appliance can be controlled by a triac, but an *induction* motor in a heavier fixed blower generally cannot be speed controlled except by re-synthesizing an AC waveform at a different frequency.  You might also consider some sort of air venting louver scheme rather than actually controlling the (ab)used motor...

Comment: Thank you for your input. When able I'll update with the specific motor. Air venting may indeed be a good solution as you mentioned.

Comment: I agree with Chris Stratton. I think I would limit the incoming air into the hair dryer as a means of controlling air flow.

Comment: I believe hair driers use a universal motor, so a common AC speed controller should work. There are tons of chines ones on Amazon and Ebay.

Comment: @bunker89320 I'd more likely divert some of the output, so as not to deprive the motor of cooling air

Comment: @ChrisStratton yea diverting the output would be easier on the motor and better overall permanent solution. Limiting the incoming air would be the quickest to test out, since all you need to do is cover a portion with thick cloth or paper. But you can only cover it so much before it becomes really hard on the motor.

Comment: Something like a pipe with a big hole in it and a sleeve that rotates or slides over that should work.  Some vacum cleaners have this on the input side.